# Adding an image interferes with existing frames

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

When trying to add an image next to a input box frame, the image causes the input boxes to move around. My code for this GUI is here. Any help is appreciated.

```
root = tk.Tk()

entry_frame = tk.Frame(root)
entry_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

a_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="a =")
a_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
a_var = tk.StringVar()
a_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, textvariable=a_var)
a_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)

b_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="b =")
b_label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
b_var = tk.StringVar()
b_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, textvariable=b_var)
b_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)

c_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="c =")
c_label.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
c_var = tk.StringVar()
c_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, textvariable=c_var)
c_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)

A_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="A =")
A_label.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
A_var = tk.StringVar()
A_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, textvariable=A_var)
A_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)

B_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="B =")
B_label.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
B_var = tk.StringVar()
B_entry = ttk.Entry(entry_frame, textvariable=B_var)
B_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=tk.E, pady=10)

C_label = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="C =")
C_label.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W)
C_var = tk.StringVar()
C_entry = ttk.Label(entry_frame, text="90")
C_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10)

triangle = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Triangle.png"))
triangle_img = ttk.Label(entry_frame, image=triangle)
triangle_img.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10)

button_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0)

calculate_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Calculate", command=trigonometry_calculator)
calculate_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

clear_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Clear", command=reset)
clear_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

quit_button = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Quit", command=done)
quit_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

The gui for this program is supposed to look normal with the input boxes, not pushed around because of the image I added.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change parent of the image label to `root` and put it at row 0 and column 1.  Also add `columnspan=2` to `button_frame.grid(...)`:

```py
...
triangle = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Triangle.png"))
triangle_img = ttk.Label(root, image=triangle) # use root as parent
triangle_img.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

button_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
button_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2) # added columnspan=2
...
```

Result:

[image]

---

Or just put the image label at row 0 column 2 with `rowspan=6`:

```py
...
triangle_img.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, rowspan=6)
...
```